# android connect to online mysql server using php scrpits online

Tags: android, json

this is my code for connect.
the error is:

10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): 
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): **Warning**:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'https' (1) in **/home/shifteb/public_html/studentreg/_android_alexmed_api/include/DB_Connect.php** on line **24**
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): 
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): **Warning**:  mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user 'shifteb'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/shifteb/public_html/studentreg/_android_alexmed_api/include/DB_Connect.php** on line **26**
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): 
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): **Warning**:  mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in **/home/shifteb/public_html/studentreg/_android_alexmed_api/include/DB_Connect.php** on line **26**
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): 
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): **Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'shifteb'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/shifteb/public_html/studentreg/_android_alexmed_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **121**
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): 
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): **Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in **/home/shifteb/public_html/studentreg/_android_alexmed_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **121**
10-16 21:33:29.300: E/JSON(359): Access denied for user 'shifteb'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
10-16 21:33:29.320: E/JSON Parser(359): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

this when i attempt to connect to online ???

The application runs perfectly in `localhost` but when I change the URL for online server and uploaded the php scripts the error above appears.

these are scripts

the functions scripts

```
<?php

/**
 * @author ziad gamal baiomy gholmish
 * @copyright 2012
 */

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    /**
     * 
     *function to search student 
     *  
     */

     public function searchStudent($method ,$information){


        if($method == 'e_mail'){

            $query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM persons WHERE `email_personal` = '$information' ");
            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($no_of_rows > 0){

                $resultset=mysql_fetch_array($query);

                return $resultset;

            }else{

                return false;
            }
        }else if($method == 'mobile'){

            $query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM persons WHERE `mobile` = '$information' ");
            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if($no_of_rows > 0){


                $resultset=mysql_fetch_array($query);

                return $resultset;
            }else{

                return false;
            }


        }else if($method =='phone'){


             $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE `phone` = '$information'");
              $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);


            if($no_of_rows > 0){


                $resultset=mysql_fetch_array($query);

                return $resultset;
            }else{

                return false;
            }
        }else if($method == 'id'){

            $information= intval($information);


             $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE `id` = $information");
             $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if($no_of_rows > 0){


                $resultset=mysql_fetch_array($query);

                return $resultset;
            }else{

                return false;
            }
        } 



     }


    /**
     * 
     *function to staff login 
     * 
     * 
     */


    public function staffLogin($username , $password){

        $hashed_password= sha1($password);

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($no_of_rows > 0){
         $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

         if($hashed_password == $result['hashed_password']){

           return $result;
         }else{

          //user not found 
          return false;
        }



   }


    }







    /**
     * 
     *function to add  staff member
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */

 public function addStaffMember($username , $password , $national_id){

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM admins WHERE `username` = '$username'");
         $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
         if($no_of_rows == 0){

            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO persons( `national_id` ) VALUES('$national_id')");

            if($query){

                $resultset=mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM persons");
                $admin = mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
                $admin_id = $admin['0'];
                $admin_id= intval($admin_id);
                $hashed_password= sha1($password);
                $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO admins (`id`, `username`, `hashed_password`) VALUES ($admin_id , '$username', '$hashed_password')");

                if($query){

                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;

                }





            }




         }





    }





    /**
     *
     *  
     * edit student information
     * 
     * 
     */



     public function editStudentInfo($f_name ,$s_name  ,$t_name ,$l_name ,$phone ,$mobile ,$e_mail ,$city ,$department ,$street ,$building,$flat ,$id){

        $id=intval($id);

        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET `english_fName`= '$f_name' , `english_sName`= '$s_name'  , `english_tName`= '$t_name' , `english_lName`= '$l_name'  , `phone`= '$phone'  , `mobile`= '$mobile' , `city`= '$city' , `p_department`= '$department' , `street`='$street'  , `building`='$building'  , `flat`='$flat'  , `email_personal`= '$e_mail' WHERE id= $id ") or die(mysql_error());


        if($query){

            return true;

        }else{

            return false;
        }




     }

     /**
      * 
      *function to change the student password 
      * 
      * 
      */


     public function changeStudentPass($old_pass , $new_pass , $id){

        $hashed_old=sha1($old_pass);
        $hashed_new=sha1($new_pass);
        $id= intval($id);

        $query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = $id AND `hashed_password` ='$hashed_old' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($no_of_rows == 1){

            $query=mysql_query("UPDATE students SET `hashed_password` = '$hashed_new' WHERE id = $id ") or die(mysql_error());
            if($query){

                return true;

            }else{

                return true;
            }



        }










     }






 /**
  * 
  *get the user by user name and password 
  * 
  */
 public function  getUserByUserNameAndPassword($username, $password){

    $hashed_password= sha1($password); 
   $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
   $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($no_of_rows > 0){
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($hashed_password == $result['hashed_password']){

        return $result;
    }else{

        //user not found 
        return false;
    }



   }



 }









    /**
     * registeration process
     * 
     * 
     */ 

 public function registerUser($english_fName , $english_sName ,  $english_tName , $english_lName ,$phone ,$mobile ,$email_personal , $sex , $religion , $city ,$p_department, $street , $building ,$flat , $birth_date , $social , $nationality ,$seat_number ,$password){

    $query=mysql_query("select * from persons p join students s on p.id =s.id and `seat_number` =$seat_number");
    if($query){

    $resultSet=mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $file_number= $resultSet['file_number'];

    $file_number= takeTodigit($file_number);

    $username=$english_fName.".".$english_tName."12".$file_number;
    $hashed_password=sha1($password);

    $email_college=$username."@alexmed.edu.eg";
    $id=$resultSet['id'];
    $birth_date=strtotime($birth_date);
    $birth_date=date('y-m-d',$birth_date);


    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE persons set `english_fName`='$english_fName' , `english_sName`='$english_sName' , `english_tName`='$english_tName' ,`english_lName`='$english_lName',`phone`='$phone' , `mobile`='$mobile'  , `email_personal`='$email_personal' , `sex`='$sex' , `religion`='$religion' ,`city`='$city' ,`p_department`='$p_department' ,`street`='$street'  , `building`='$building' ,`flat`='$flat' ,`social`='$social' , `nationality`='$nationality' ,`email_college`='$email_college' ,`birth_date`='$birth_date'  WHERE `id`=$id ");
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE students set `username`= '$username' ,`hashed_password`='$hashed_password' ,`active` = 1");
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE `id`=$id ");
    if($query){

        $resultSet=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        return $resultSet;
    }else{
        return false;

    }
            }
    }




 /**
  *add new student
  *  
  * 
  */
  public function addNewStudent($fName ,$sName ,$tName,$lName,$national_id,$seat_number,$total_grades){

$issuance_of=getissuanceof($national_id);


    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO persons(`arabic_fName` , `arabic_sName` ,`arabic_tName` ,`arabic_lName` , `national_id` ,`issuance_of`) VALUES ('$fName' ,'$sName','$tName' ,'$lName' ,'$national_id' ,'$issuance_of')");

    if ($query) {
        //Success!
        //Generating student id:
        $resultset = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM persons");
        $student = mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
        $student_id = $student['0'];
        //Inserting into the studens' table:
        $date = date('Y-m-d');

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO students (`id` , `seat_number` ,`total_grades` , `file_number` , `join_date`  ) VALUES ('$student_id', '$seat_number', '$total_grades' ,'$student_id' , '$date')");

        if ($query){
              //Generating student id:  
   $student_id= intval($student_id);
     $resultset = mysql_query("SELECT `file_number` FROM students WHERE id =$student_id");
        $student = mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
      $file_number_2= $student['file_number'];
        $student_number =(int) generate_snumber($file_number_2);
        mysql_query("UPDATE students SET `student_number`=$student_number WHERE `file_number` =$file_number_2");    
        return true;
            }else{
                    die(mysql_error());

        }



            }

  }


public function search_Seat_Number($s_seat_number){


  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE `seat_number` =$s_seat_number");

  if($query){

  if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){


  return false;

  }else{

    return true;
  }

  }else{

    return false;
  }

  }
 }

function generate_snumber($file_number){

      $file_number= strval($file_number);
      if(strlen($file_number) == 1){


        $file_number= "000".$file_number;
      }
      else if(strlen($file_number) == 2){


        $file_number= "00".$file_number;
      }

      else if(strlen($file_number) == 3){

        $file_number = "0".$file_number;
      }

      $student_number= "12".$file_number;
      return $student_number;



  }

  function takeTodigit($file_number){

    if(strlen($file_number) == 1){
 $file_number = "0".$file_number;
       }
       if(strlen($file_number) == 2 )
       {

        $file_number =$file_number;
       }

       if(strlen($file_number) ==3){

        $file_number = substr($file_number, -2);

       }
       if(strlen($file_number) == 4){

        $file_number= substr($file_number, -2);
       }
       return $file_number;


  }



  function getissuanceof($national_id){



  $issuance_of=$national_id[7].$national_id[8];
  return $issuance_of;     
    }










?>
```

the config script is :

```
<?php

/**
 * @author ziad gamal baiomy gholmish
 * @copyright 2012
 */
/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "https://supremecenter10.se/pma/index.php?token=a8aa13f9715f82765b6d101b2b1a43ff");
define("DB_USER", "ultratech_mobdb");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "******"// the password );
define("DB_DATABASE", "******//the username here ");

?>
```

the connect script :

```
<?php

/**
 * @author ziad gamal baiomy gholmish
 * @copyright 2012
 */


    class DB_Connect {

        // constructor
        function __construct() {

        }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() {
            // $this->close();
        }

        // Connecting to database
        public function connect() {
            require_once 'config.php';
            // connecting to mysql
            $con = mysql_connect("https://supremecenter10.se/pma/index.php?token=a8aa13f9715f82765b6d101b2b1a43ff", "username" ,"password");
            // selecting database
            mysql_select_db("https://supremecenter10.se/pma/index.php?token=a8aa13f9715f82765b6d101b2b1a43ff");

            // return database handler
            return $con;
        }

        // Closing database connection
        public function close() {
            mysql_close();
        }

    }




    ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to contact your server administrator because your scripts look fine. May be there is some issue with the server.. Kindly check with the admin to see if there is any error.

Comment: hi i contact the host help and they send me this messgae. i want know are my script have error or what and what i should reply to them ? the message is : The error messages on the image are some custom script related ones, which we are not familiar with since third party script support services are not offered. Could you please let us know of the purpose of this script and what it is used for you, so we can try to provide some advices for you. Looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are probably the same problem discussed in this question here on SO:
[Null Pointer Exception while retrieving JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11070290/1455421).

Take a look at the solutions provided in the above link. I hope this helps.

Comment: but i here send data and the program as i said runs perfectly on the local host 
the php scripts are
is error in this  'echo json_encode($response);'

Comment: Where are you using echo json_encode($response); You mean on the server side?? Try and run your scripts in a browser and check if the output returned is in proper JSON format. May be there is some problem on your server side scripts.. If so, then post your script code here.