# i can't parse JSON value getting JSON value and getting Null Exception

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-asynctask

I'm using Google map api Autocomplete , And trying to fetch the images of searched places , i got null value in Json Parser 
Please help me

```
 public class PlaceJSONParserO {

    public Place[] parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        Log.e("PlaceJSONParserO"," call");
        JSONArray jPlaces = null;
        try {
            jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
            Log.e("PlaceJSONParserO jplaces", String.valueOf(jPlaces));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Catch-->",e.toString()); //got the exception here 
        }

        return getPlaces(jPlaces);
    }

    private Place[] getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {

        int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
        Place[] places = new Place[placesCount];
        Log.e("Count", String.valueOf(placesCount));
        Log.e("Places ddd", places.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i <= placesCount; i++) {
            try {

                places[i] = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
                Log.e("get data information    ",places[i].toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("catch exeption data",e.toString());
            }
        }
        return places;
    }

    private Place getPlace(JSONObject jPlace) {
        Log.e("JSON PLACE",jPlace.toString());
        Place place = new Place();

        try {
            // Extracting Place name, if available
            if (!jPlace.isNull("long_name")) {

                place.mPlaceName = jPlace.getString("long_name");
                Log.e("Name==",place.mPlaceName);

            }
            // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
            if (!jPlace.isNull("short_name")) {
                place.mVicinity = jPlace.getString("short_name");
            }

            if (!jPlace.isNull("photos")) {
                JSONArray photos = jPlace.getJSONArray("photos");
                place.mPhotos = new Photo[photos.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                    place.mPhotos[i] = new Photo();
                    place.mPhotos[i].mWidth = ((JSONObject) photos.get(i)).getInt("width");
                    place.mPhotos[i].mHeight = ((JSONObject) photos.get(i)).getInt("height");
                    place.mPhotos[i].mPhotoReference = ((JSONObject) photos.get(i)).getString("photo_reference");
                    JSONArray attributions = ((JSONObject) photos.get(i)).getJSONArray("html_attributions");
                    place.mPhotos[i].mAttributions = new Attribution[attributions.length()];
                    for (int j = 0; j < attributions.length(); j++) {
                        place.mPhotos[i].mAttributions[j] = new Attribution();
                        place.mPhotos[i].mAttributions[j].mHtmlAttribution = attributions.getString(j);
                    }
                }
            }
            place.mLat = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            place.mLng = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.toString());
        }
        Log.e("Details places", String.valueOf(place));
        return place;
    }
}
}
```

And this is my JSON call On Maps activity

```
  private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                Log.e("url do back", url[0]); //here i got the URL
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e("pasrde", result);  // the result get the currect JSON
            ParserTask parserTask1 = new ParserTask();

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                parserTask1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            else
                parserTask1.execute(result);

        }
    }
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Place[]> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected Place[] doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
            Place[] places = null;

            Log.e("json data > ",jsonData.toString());

            PlaceJSONParserO placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParserO(); // After the call getting null value, so execute the exception

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

                Log.e("JSON Object","tst"+places);

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Place[] places) {
....
}
```

JSON Value like this

```
{   "html_attributions" : [],   "result" : {      "address_components" : [         {            "long_name" : "Kollam",            "short_name" : "Kollam",            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]         },         {            "long_name" : "Kollam",            "short_name" : "KLM",            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]         },         {            "long_name" : "Kerala",            "short_name" : "KL",            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]         },         {            "long_name" : "India",            "short_name" : "IN",            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]         },         {            "long_name" : "691001",            "short_name" : "691001",            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]         }      ],      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eKollam\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eKerala\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e691001\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eIndia\u003c/span\u003e",      "formatted_address" : "Kollam, Kerala 691001, India",      "geometry" : {         "location" : {            "lat" : 8.8932118,            "lng" : 76.6141396         },         "viewport" : {            "northeast" : {               "lat" : 8.898130699999999,               "lng" : 76.61599149999999            },            "southwest" : {               "lat" : 8.874412099999999,               "lng" : 76.57168419999999            }         }      },      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",      "id" : "c880d95b212b2461e5dd9927ba351c29f5c4cf2c",      "name" : "Kollam",      "photos" : [         {            "height" : 2848,            "html_attributions" : [               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117303089050910364610/photos\"\u003elekshmi vegway\u003c/a\u003e"            ],            "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAAEimH48mlgdsY7EdfdphfJwa6-7-8MjooXZqTWBb1hponUzcZhhf-aMJO8L3xQXxtcmDZIj3uXj68m91nbKX5LyCIWBYvQsgwOgv8G_--BLAN3fFIjcP-w2p8G7yhpU3ydroQLWF1Z_ddEn801PQZbxZyp_daeDICujE3rK5xHQ0EhCquFrvT5T-6HpyH_MCE8uFGhTWe3Eyv7e0r99IAQZ1YfTO3r_6Wg",            "width" : 4288         },         {            "height" : 1152,            "html_attributions" : [               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106519267907454252415/photos\"\u003eJiju Paravur\u003c/a\u003e"            ],            "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAAKIbOVXGQfDpuovBkOOaqE_OgFVBWfb0pwlPj6854EQ6LGJrSK5HX5SvD_WSZE3P8Ntq8m93grV1kFIzk_T1Xs5iUpH3GB-uICqyQFOiKLXk6PN8k0GmDgqD-79-VhQgZkvORE0PKwiN6vX88u0rg0HdwCNK-Vj_tm6sufz1jC8qEhAKnJ-JZQXYBMQSx-ywwC63GhQs1_r4asSxuKigWdGWj6APrCyTpg",            "width" : 2048         },         {            "height" : 720,            "html_attributions" : [               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115352225097306538446/photos\"\u003eRoby Thankachan\u003c/a\u003e"            ],            "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAHU5x0qkwzytr9A7FHn-cdklYaSm0GvBHBHnprzY_zEtT06jIV1l1oyizCi7N73nvXPZoNGpe9ruUD75-AC8tvKr6TphNCR_S_5CByGz8I70acvIVV8VvVs0oRvxmYMKVOTBxOA6l3G1gIUpEvQPCWSMa6AbQEVQ1y_YTqQ8h9O_EhB7v5oSjAhboOw_9RQOZ93HGhTdb4jMNpC8FXTfM6w9HNbgYsCjUA",            "width" : 960         },         {            "height" : 704,            "html_attributions" : [               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112849338948952733528/photos\"\u003eEiffel Bastin\u003c/a\u003e"            ],            "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAALNUi-ooozDAmBbOwrxnfrF73s7JdJtrhinJShhKvQfjsbQKKlpU0hviceNaLYfYYTSaXgNh7eevU-DJt2PgMPyVy2_yi0NTUJP7Ffwbqae7IxxCDiE2h1GgvmbiYIpqNnLsSzPCIlpM-iLGVOXvIpi1Z6aAiCxre-PBnVklglBwEhDJU20ztQ1LtGB35OovuJyYGhQCHCLO3VKQHfCwpV3Wjccd2sfk-Q",            "width" : 2208         },         {            "height" : 960,            "html_attributions" : [               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116245421984595223878/photos\"\u003eAppu B\u003c/a\u003e"            ],            "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAAKDr605tHHV6"
```

How to i fetch the Photo reference ? Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Exception while retrieving JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069894/null-pointer-exception-while-retrieving-json-object)

Comment: @ironman i got json value but  not executing the PlaceJSONParser ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing json object,not json array